# Can't convert memory address to value

Tags: c++, data-structures, set

thanks for visiting my question! Currently, when I run this code (an implementation of the Set data structure in c++), the memory address of each element in the set is printed instead of the values in the set. To help with debugging, here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

#define PB push_back
typedef std::vector<int> vint;

class SetBase
{
public:
  SetBase() {}
  ~SetBase() {}

  void insert(int x)
  {
    if (!this->isInSet(x))
    {
      this->set.PB(x);
    }
  }

  int size()
  {
    return this->set.size();
  }

  bool empty()
  {
    return this->size() == 0;
  }

  int operator[](int index)
  {
    if (index >= 0 && index < this->size())
    {
      return this->set[index];
    }
    else
    {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  bool find(int target)
  {
    sort(this->set.begin(), this->set.end());

    int low = 0, high = this->size();

    while (low <= high)
    {
      long long mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
      long long guess = this->set[mid];

      if (guess == target)
        return true;
      else if (guess < target)
        low = mid + 1;
      else
        high = mid - 1;
    }

    return false;
  }

  int count(int target)
  {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->set.size(); i++)
    {
      if (this->set[i] == target)
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
  }

  bool operator=(SetBase &other)
  {
    if (other.size() != this->size())
      return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < other.size(); i++)
    {
      if (other[i] != this->set[i])
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

private:
  vint set;

  bool isInSet(int target)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++)
    {
      if (set[i] == target)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
};

class Set : public SetBase
{
public:
  void set_union(Set *set1, Set *set2, Set &back_insertor)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < set1->size(); i++)
    {
      if (this->isInSet(back_insertor, i))
      {
        back_insertor.insert(i);
      }
    }
  }

  void set_difference(Set set1, Set set2, Set &back_insertor)
  {
    // set_difference = set1 - set2
  }

  void set_intersection(Set set1, Set set2, Set &back_insertor)
  {
    // set_difference = set1 U set2
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.size(); i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < set2.size(); j++)
      {
        if (set1[i] == set2[j])
        {
          back_insertor.insert(set1[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void printSet(Set *in)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < in->size(); i++)
    {
      std::cout << &in[i] << "\n";
    }
  }

private:
  bool isInSet(SetBase set1, int target)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.size(); i++)
    {
      if (target == set1[i])
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Set *set_1 = new Set();
  Set *set_2 = new Set();
  Set *back = new Set();

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    set_1->insert(i);

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    set_2->insert(i);

  set_2->insert(11);

  set_1->set_union(set_1, set_2, *back);
  set_1->printSet(set_1);

  delete set_1;
  delete set_2;
  delete back;
}
```

When running the `set_1->printSet(set_1);` line, here's what I get:

```
0x7fb498c05a20
0x7fb498c05a38
0x7fb498c05a50
0x7fb498c05a68
0x7fb498c05a80
0x7fb498c05a98
0x7fb498c05ab0
0x7fb498c05ac8
0x7fb498c05ae0
0x7fb498c05af8
```

Even though this works, I would like to print out the values (integer) instead. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question so it contains your [mcve] in the question itself (making it self-contained, links can disappear or have their contents changed).

Comment: The key being _minimal_. 99% of this program is unrelated to your problem. Make a new toy program that _only contains the problem_. This is debugging legwork you have to do before posting. Remember you're competing for our free time! Good luck.

Comment: Hey there, @Someprogrammerdude, I have updated the post. Thanks for the handy resources!

Comment: There are two keys, both equally important. Reproducible: The code describes a complete program that produces the undesirable behaviour. Minimal: The program consists only of code that directly produces the undesirable behaviour. When you have the code reduced to the required level, you have a program this is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. At that point it's usually pretty easy to see what the bug is, even if you don't know why it's a bug or how to fix it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `printSet()`, you use `&in[i]` to print each element.

The `&` operator returns the *address* of the object you are referencing. So, instead of getting the *value*, you are getting its address.  You should remove it, eg:

```
void printSet(Set *in)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < in->size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << (*in)[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @RemyLebeau!